# API authentication confusion

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth, go

My question is not deeply technical but more of a system architectural one.

I'm designing an API backend in Go Lang. I'd like to have several clients, like a web server, cell phones etc.. I imagine that all these clients should have a secret API key so to validate that they can use the API. At the same time the web frontend is going to have a lot of users with different restrictions. I'd like for these users to be able to log in with their facebook or Google account. That should require OAuth authentication as I understand. My question is now where should I add the OAuth. Only in the frontend and then save the user in session or also between the frontend and the backend. I'm highly confused about how I should set up this communication and authentication.

I'm building the web  server in PHP and I'd like the web frontend to be really light weight and more or less only function as en empty shell/view for the Go API. I've build systems in plain PHP/MySQL before but I'd like to make a shift to Go based APIs.

How would a URI look like to the API from the web server frontend for let's say a show profile page? I imagine something like a GET call to "http.//backend.com:3000/[api-key]/[api-secret][oauth-token?]/profile. Then some middleware to authenticate the web client and another piece of middleware to authenticate the user. Would that be "the right" approach?

I hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your facebook or google developer docs, you will find examples on how to integrate with their oauth login systems.

OAuth, or at least the last step of it, really must be done on the back end as you have to assume your front end is a bad guy hitting your system.

For go oauth, take a look at: https://github.com/golang/oauth2

You will likely have a `http.HandlerFunc("/oauth/google",yourGoogleFunc)` 
and `http.HandlerFunc("/oauth/facebook",yourFBFunc)`
type thing, then you register that URL on your dev account with those companies.

while testing, it's easiest to use localhost:8080 (or whatever) as the callback url so it works on any machine as long as you are using a local browser.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How would a URI look like to the API from the web  server frontend for let's say a show profile page? I imagine something like a GET call to "http.//backend.com:3000/[api-key]/[api-secret][oauth-token?]/profile. Then some middleware to authenticate the web client and another piece of middleware to authenticate the user. Would that be "the right" approach?

Comment: Kind of depends on if you plan on using their google/fb credentials for anything than just authentication.  For example, do you want to post on their FB wall from your server?   For my apps, it's auth only.  Once I verify the login, i just create my own session to track my user.  Basically, i have sites where I don't have any passwords, just users associated to google/fb profiles.  I'd rather leave the security to people with more to lose than I.   for Go sessions, look at: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions

Comment: I'm only going to use it for authentication as well. Hmm, see I've a small problem with the session stuff since I've been taught that a RESTful API should be stateless and keeping sessions kinda breaks that rule - at the same time maybe that what gets me confused.

Comment: the problem is that you can't trust the client to not be a bad guy.  so you need something to store who they are.  the gorilla sessions can store them as cookies, which makes them server side stateless.   but cookies are weird to manage for non-browser based clients.

Comment: But I can trust the web server if I use an api key/secret between my client and my own web server, right? That would only allow my client to talk to the api. Furthermore I could encrypt the communication between the two of them.

Comment: If you have web based clients, how do you expect to keep secret key, secret?  All someone has to do is view source and they have your key and can now talk to your api server.   Or use a proxy / sniffer with the mobile app

Comment: I see your point but then again if they can read the source code they already have access to the server. They would be able to read the database password anyway then. I could use an encrypted connection between the webserver and the api server too and I have both servers on the same infrastructure so listening to them requires some kind of access to the system. The customers webbrowser is not going to show the URI for the API but only for the web server.